# how to make custom website infinite scrolling change the URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url-rewriting, infinite-scroll, friendly-url

I plan to make a news portal where I plan to make a post page where if the user keeps scrolling, the next post keeps appearing as well as the URL keeps changing. A typical example will be the healthline.com website
and for reference, the following URL might be an example

https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/an-apple-a-day-keeps-the-doctor-away

Comment: `history.pushState(anything goes here, page_title, url)`

Comment: So many ways, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-update-url-on-scroll, http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/2ZjWP/8/ , http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/ . It all comes down to either pushState manipulation or given an element or article an ID hash when in view. Can be all done by yourself via Intersection Oberserver API or use a library, like the above mentioned

Answer (score 1):

history.pushState and history.replaceState can do it
The example use history.replaceState.
If you rewrite the replaceState func in the console, you can see the call infomation